# Bazaar: Ignoring files locally but not in centralized repository?

Tags: ignore, bazaar

We have a centralized development server, with everyone working from local checkouts. How can we ignore a specific directory only in our *local repositories* and not in the *centralized repository*?

Some background information: The project is a Drupal site, and the *files* directory of this site is always in flux. As we don't want any changes to the local *files* directory to be committed to the centralized repo, we ignore this directory using .bzrignore. The problem is that this means the *files* directory on the centralized development server will also be ignored, which is not what we want. We want to get its changes when updating/checking out, but not be able to commit our own changes to the *files* directory.

Comment: Just for information, I haven't test this, but maybe you can try to extract the *files* folder as another repository and link it as externals (thx to bzr-externals). So when you commit your project, you commit only the main checkout, not the externals.

http://launchpad.net/bzr-externals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it seems not to be possible to perform such a task directly. It is, however, already added to the wishlist in [bzr issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/209025).

Comment: I'm surprised to see the issue hasn't received more attention! I would think this was a common scenario when developing websites/web applications. Someone at work found a workaround, by adding an absolute path to the global "~/.bazaar/ignore" file. Not ideal though.

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use views to hide them. Just generate a view with just the files you want to keep.

To do this with on my Mac OS X machine I ran the following commands:

```
find dir1/ dir2/ | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g' | xargs bzr view --name keep-versioned
```

All the files in your working copy directory not in dir1 or dir2 will be ignored until you delete the view, like so:

```
bzr view --delete --name keep-versioned
```

Comment: Thanks I have a similar problem and was thinking about a solution, I'll try yours at some point. I think the only problem with this is that if you add eg. dir3 which you want in your view, then you have to remember to add it.

Answer (score 0):

For global usage you can set pattern in:
~/.bazaar/ignore

I have version Bazaar 2.5.1 and it works.

Comment: Does this allow local ignore but _not_ central ignore? That's what the OP wants...